# Raspberry Pi Livestream

Tags: streaming-video

I was asked by two of my teachers to set up a live stream outdoors so they can see the incoming winter wonderland (their office is totally enclosed and has no natural light). I have been browsing many ways to try and accomplish this but they said that they'd prefer it to not be an online stream. Is there any way to do this without creating a stream that will be posted to the internet?

Comment: Will your Pi be on the same network as the devices that you want to stream to?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will need to launch  a file server on the RPi.
For instance Flask server is easy to set up.
See more informations [in this tutorial](https://videos.cctvcamerapros.com/raspberry-pi/how-to-setup-video-streaming-server.html) if you give your tongue ...